# Android TextView fromHtml() how to support unsupported css style, text size?

Tags: android, html, kotlin, textview, fromhtml

I'm using this:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(html, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

How to add support of text size regarding a fact that font-size isn't natively supported?

I don't want to override whole paragraph text - other styles works well.
Using regex or parse html through different library may lead to problems as part of a text may have bigger font or parser may work differently. Also a webview isn't a sollution.

Example html:

```html
<p style="font-size:30px">TEST</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Android HTML did not support all the tags of HTML.
Font color is working fine with Android HTML, but font size is not supported.
You can use `<small>`, `<big>` tags for Android HTML

```
Html.fromHtml("<big>" + "First name" + "</big>" + "<br />" + "<small>" + "Last name" + "</small>", Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

You can [check here](https://github.com/Cheticamp/Miscellaneous/blob/main/Html%20Tag%20Support.pdf) which tags are supported with Android HTML

Comment: Thanks for an answer. I saw documentation :) If I could I would change html tags. Unfortunately I am getting it from server. So far I added jsoup to parse html and added missing formats, but it isn't ideal.

Comment: Hey @kkkkk. Do you use jsoup directly or some library wrapper?

Comment: @TaxistSamael problem solved long ago. I wrote a custom Html.TagHandler and I added a custom implementation for tags that weren't supported correctly for my use.